# Time reversal operator acting on $|sm\rangle$ and the $UK$ decomposition

Tags: operators, quantum-spin, time-reversal-symmetry

I'm learning the [time reversal operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry#Time_reversal_in_quantum_mechanics:%7E:text=examine%20these%20next.-,Time%20reversal%20in%20quantum%20mechanics,-%5Bedit%5D) from [Notes by Littlejohn](https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/notes/timerev.pdf).  In a system with spin, time reversal operator $\Theta$ can be decomposed,
$$
\Theta=\exp(-\mathrm i\pi S_y/\hbar )K_s,\tag{1}
$$
where anti-linear operator $K_s$ is the operation of taking complex conjugation in spin basis,
$$
K_s|sm\rangle=|sm\rangle,\tag{2}
$$
where $|sm\rangle$ is the eigenstate of $S_z$.
In Sect.11 of the above note, the transform property of spin,
$$
\Theta \vec S \Theta^\dagger = -\vec S,\tag{2}
$$
is used to obtain
$$
\Theta|sm\rangle=(-)^{s-m}|s(-m)\rangle.\tag{3}
$$

My question is: now we have Eq.(1), can we derive Eq.3 directly? I tried
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Theta|sm\rangle &= \exp(-\mathrm i\pi S_y/\hbar) K|sm\rangle
\\&=\exp(-\mathrm i\pi S_y/\hbar) |sm\rangle
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi^n}{n!(\mathrm i\hbar)^n} S_y^n |sm\rangle,
\end{aligned}\tag4
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_y|sm\rangle &= \frac 1{2\mathrm i}(S_+-S_-)|sm\rangle
\\& = \frac{1}{2\mathrm i}\left(\sqrt{s(s+1}-m(m+1)|s(m+1\rangle - \sqrt{s(s+1)-m(m-1)}|s(m-1\rangle\right). 
\end{aligned}\tag5
$$
Though for spin-$1/2$ particles the exponetial can be reduced to pauli matrix, in general case it's not that simple. Are there ways to simplify the derivation?

Comment: Maybe my question can be reduced to prove $\exp(-\mathrm i\pi S_y/\hbar)|sm\rangle=(-)^{s-m}|sm\rangle$. I don't find it in my group theory textbook.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/530632/289541, and it seems that the proof cannot escape from using upper and lower operator. I voted to close this question.